# Chrome CSS changes appearing directly in source css file

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, netbeans, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently working on a PHP project using Netbeans IDE and MAMP server.
I opened the project in Chrome and for testing and experementing I changed some CSS styles using DevTools.

After reloading the page the changes were still there. Then I noticed, that all css changes were also done in the original css source file.

I'm wokring since 2 years with Google Chrome DevTools, but this never happened to me.

How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: I know about caching, but I think you didn't get the question.

Comment: Do you have `.css.map` files ?

Comment: @AdrienXL No, in my source folder there only .css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using NetBeans Chrome Connector plugin in Chrome, it by default propagates changes from Dev Tools to CSS/JS files. If you want to disable it, open Chrome Dev Tools, switch to NetBeans tab and uncheck the checkbox.